# Is it possible to navigate to assemblies definitions inside Visual Studio Code

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code several days as MonoDevelop replacement in Unity3D on Mac OS. I installed mono via homebrew as suggested to let VS Code to parse system assemblies. Everything works almost great, but I can't navigate definitions that are not part of my code. For example I can't go to definition of System.String or UnityEngine.Vector3 to see methods signatures. MonoDevelop has Assembly browser but I miss it in VS Code. Does anybody know if VS Code has such feature? Maybe I need to setup something for that?

**PS: I've posted feature request. If you're interested in this feature vote for it, please.
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/14698887-implement-net-assembly-browser**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems VS Code now can do that with the new extension [ms-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) for C# support. Previously it was recommended to use [Legacy C# Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.omnisharp) for Unity3D. I don't know exactly if this recommendation is still valid, but I tried to uninstall legacy and to install normal one. After some background work OmniSharp parsed my files and now it can open classes from assemblies! Look at this picture, it has open AnimationCurve class as [metadata]!
[image]
I'm trying it with Unity3D 5.5.0b2 beta now, so I'm not sure if this will work with production release of Unity3D. By the way I also removed VSCode plugin from dotBunny out of project as Unity3D 5.5 supports Visual Studio Code self.